# What does shouldUpdate do in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

The [docs](https://ant.design/components/form-cn#shouldupdate) say:

> When shouldUpdate is true, any Form update will cause the Form.Item to
> be re-rendered. This is very helpful for custom rendering some areas:
>
> ```
> <Form.Item shouldUpdate>   {() => {
>     return <pre>{JSON.stringify(form.getFieldsValue(), null, 2)}</pre>;   }} 
> </Form.Item>
> ```

But that doesn't seem to be happening - with `shouldUpdate={true}` the `Form.Item` doesn't get rerendered.

When shouldUpdate is a function, the function does get called, but even though it returns true, the children of the Form.Item don't get rerendered.

I made an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-shouldupdate-testing-f4c9hn?file=/App.tsx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens exactly as the documentation says. `Form.item` rerenders. In React if parent rerenders it does not mean that the children will too. Since you pass children to `Form.Item` as `ReactElement (component instance)`, the only way to make that children rerender by its parent is by cloning them. And probably it does not doing that, since it already supports contexts and render prop. If you want to rerender its children together with `Form.Item`, you should pass the children as `render prop` instead of `component instance`. Just like in the documentation

```
<Form.Item shouldUpdate>   
   {() => <div>this will rerender together with its parent Form.Item </div> } 
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, It looks like `shouldComponentUpdate` in class. This will listen for a specific item value changes in the form. Then, decide to re-render `<Component />` or not (depends on your logic inside). It will be more powerful than `dependencies`.

`form.setFieldValue("name", value")` will trigger `shouldUpdate`

```
<Form.Item shouldUpdate={(prevValue, curValue) => {
  // your logic to make this <Component /> re-render
  // Return true/false
}
  {() => {
    return <Component />
  }}
</Form.Item>
```

In case, you only want enter a `<Input />` or click a `<Radio />` by yourself (Input or Radio belongs to form) and make `<Component />` re-render. You can think of `dependencies`.

```
<Form.Item
   dependencies={[
     "inputName",
     "radioName"
  ]}
>
  {() => {
    return <Component />
  }}
</Form.Item>
```

`form.setFieldValue("name", value")` **won't** trigger `dependencies`